# What options does an italian speaker have to query synonyms on the internet?

Tags: network, thesaurus

I use [thesaurus_query.vim](https://github.com/Ron89/thesaurus_query.vim), but

> Currently this plugin Supports only English (en), Chinese (cn), French (fr), Russian (ru) and German (de) thesaurus query

I'm not sure if this simply means that the default for the `g:tq_enabled_backends` variable only contains servers for those languages (and I'd simply have to add another appropriate item to the list), or something else.

---

I've tried what suggested in the comments, but it didn't work out. I've basically swapped the files of Italian and German, but it didn't work out. Here's an error I get when querying for a synonym with the cursor on the word *trovare*

```
Error detected while processing function thesaurus_query#Thesaurus_Query_Lookup:                           
line   40:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 10, in <module>
  File "/home/enrico/.vim/plugged/thesaurus_query.vim/autoload/thesaurus_query/thesaurus_query.py", line 94, in qu
ery
    [state, synonym_list]=self.query_backends[query_backend_curr].query(word)
  File "/home/enrico/.vim/plugged/thesaurus_query.vim/autoload/thesaurus_query/backends/openoffice_en_lookup.py", 
line 46, in query
    num_groups = int(header.strip().split(u'|')[1])
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'tagliare in pezzetti'
line   44:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'tq_synonym_result' is not defined
```

I know that the file is read because the string `tagliare in pezzetti` is in that file indeed.

I suspect that the plugin makes some assumption on the format of the `*.dat` file, but I'm not sure.

Comment: The Plugin currently has no support for Italian. Assuming you will not use Chinese/French/German , you can use a work-around to use local backend thesaurus of OPENOffice : take the Italian files th_it_IT_v2.idx & th_it_IT_v2.dat & rename to Chinese/French/German files (which-ever you will not use in general) & then select that "fake" language in the Plugin. I think that , it will make the Plugin think that it is a "supported" language but you will get Italian Suggestions !

Comment: Want to clarify my Earlier Comment : With this Process , we are changing the Contents of Chinese language files to Italian Content , hence when we select Chinese , we will get Italian Suggestions.

Comment: I tried, but the trick doesn't work, unfortunately :/